# How do I solve a pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

While doing database backup using pg_dump utilities I am getting below error.

```
root@lab1:~# pg_dump -Fc -h localhost -U postgres hrdb -f hrdb.dmp
Password: 
pg_dump: server version: 12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1); pg_dump version: 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Comment: There could be two pg_dump binaries on your system. Try to locate them, and call the correct one by using an absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have two versions of Postgres installed:

- Version 10.10 (`Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`), which is pre-packaged with Ubuntu 18.04
- Version 12.0 (`Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1`) installed via PGDG Apt repository

You can do any of the following:

- Use `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump` by typing out the whole path
- Use `apt` to uninstall `postgresql` (not `postgresql-12`)
- Ubuntu actually wraps several PG commands into a program called `pg_wrapper`, so you can actually do the following without having to make any changes: `pg_dump -Fc -h localhost -U postgres --cluster=12/localhost:$PGPORT hrdb -f hrdb.dmp`